# Highstock - How to change tooltip color

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a highstock chart similar to this example - http://jsfiddle.net/93HQn/2/. What I"m trying to add is for the % value in the tooltip to be red if it is a negative value or green if it is positive value. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks,
Linda

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color of any potion of the tooltip based on a value or calculation.  I modified your [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/93HQn/4/) to show how to change the color of the percentage based on if it is positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

Define a `formatter` function for your tooltips:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

With that you should be able to take full control of the tooltip contents.

Comment: Is it possible to change the actual background color with this though? Without getting rid of the pointer arrow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772038/highcharts-tooltip-background-according-to-line-without-setting-backgroundcolor