# Highcharts tooltip background according to line (without setting backgroundColor = null)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, highcharts

I have this exact same issue: [Highcharts tooltip background according to line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742013/highcharts-tooltip-background-according-to-line)

but the solutions provided here do not work for me because setting backgroundColor to null makes the pointer arrow disappear: [image]

Hence why I have been working with trying to update the tooltip background color from the formatter itself where I have access to the series color:

```
      args.options = Object.assign(args.options, {backgroundColor : this.series.color});
      this.color = this.series.color;
```

But for some reason only the initial color replacement works for me. Then subsequent tooltips show the color that I updated the first time.

First hover: [image]
Second hover: [image]

AND

First hover: [image]
Second hover: [image]

Demo of issue: http://jsfiddle.net/GGQ2a/23/

Refresh the page a couple times and hover on different series to see the issue.

I need to change the color on every hover and for some reason the replacement only gets picked up the first time arround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `Tooltip.refresh()` method and change the tooltip's background according to the point's series color.

```
const H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (p, point, mouseEvents) {
  p.call(this, point, mouseEvents);

  const label = this.label;

  if (point && label) {
    label.attr({
      fill: point.series.color
    });
  }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/t38x6kug/

Comment: The problem with this solution (although it does work!) is that I am using reactJS and when I modify the highcharts tooltip proptype this way, it changes ALL my highcharts on the page to follow this color scheme. Is there a way to speciify this in my config object?

Comment: Basically that solution extends Highcharts library - so a clean way to handle this is making another file with the wrapper and load it as a regular plugin for Highcharts. You can add one more check, e.g. if  backgroundColor is set to 'series' - and then set it or not in the options for the chart - http://jsfiddle.net/t38x6kug/1/